# Решаю задачу пирамида, но разместить результат в виде пирамиды не получается

Tags: python, циклы, for

```
n = int(input())
b = int(0)
for i in range(0, n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print (j, end='')
    for k in range (i+1,0,-1):
        print(k, end ='')
    print('')
```

Comment: Что именно не получается ?

Comment: Сделать именно пирамидой, те цикл вывожу а отцентрировать никак, ввел доп. переменную k которая равна сумму всех элементов строки, вне зависимости от заполнения, а  как все вывести ступор, понимаю, что надо в строки переводить, но выдает ошибку

Comment: n = int(input())
b = int(0)
k = n*2-1
for i in range(0, n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print (j, end='')
    for k in range (i+1,0,-1):
        print(k, end ='')
    k1 =str(k)
    
    print('')
    print ( ''*k1-1, j*1, end ='')

Comment: это  мой последний код, не судите строго, если есть возможность подскажите направление решения.

Comment: воспользуйтесь кнопкой "править" под вопросом, чтобы исправить вопрос

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос условие задачи.

Comment: Выведите лесенку из n ступенек, i я ступенька состоит из чисел от 1 до i , и обратно

Comment: n = int (input())
a = 0
for i in range(1, n+1):
  step = ' '*(n-i)
  for j in range (1, i+1):
      step +=str(j)     
  for k in range (i+1, 1 , -1):
      step +=str(k)
  print(step)

Comment: вот так получилось